# Webpack Uglify causes routing to stop work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, bundling-and-minification, webpack

When I uglify webpack bundle, routing stops work without any error message or log message. I am using oclazyload to lazy load.

**Route.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var routeConfig = function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.min.html',
                title: 'Home',
                ncyBreadcrumb: {
                    label: 'Home'
                }
            })
            .state('organizationStructure', {
                url: '/organizationStructure',
                templateUrl: 'app/admin/organizationStructure/manageHierarchy/manageHierarchyShell.min.html',
                'abstract': true,
                ncyBreadcrumb: {
                    skip: true
                },
                resolve: ['$q', '$ocLazyLoad', function($q, $ocLazyLoad) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();

                    require.ensure([], function() {
                        var mod = require('./organizationStructure.module.js');
                        $ocLazyLoad.load({
                            name: 'app.organizationStructure'
                        });
                        deferred.resolve(mod.controller);
                    });

                    return deferred.promise;
                }]
            })
            .state('organizationStructure.organization', {
                url: '/organization',
                templateUrl: 'app/admin/organizationStructure/manageHierarchy/organization/index.min.html',
                controller: 'ManageOrganization',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                title: 'Manage Organization',
                ncyBreadcrumb: {
                    label: 'Manage Organization',
                    parent: 'home'
                }
            });
    }

    app.config(routeConfig);
    return routeConfig;
};
```

**Module.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ui.router',
    'restangular',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ncy-angular-breadcrumb',
    'oc.lazyLoad'
]);
```

**Base Route**

```
require('./app.route.js')(app);
```

When I minify the bundle, app routing stops working. Otherwise it works fine. Please provide me a solution. Also I am using ngAnnotate. Dependencies are injected safely in minified file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the latest version of ui-router, which has a newer and slightly different way of handling the `resolve` block. It takes an object map.

Try this:

```
    resolve: {
       foo: ['$q', '$ocLazyLoad', function($q, $ocLazyLoad) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                require.ensure([], function() {
                    var mod = require('./organizationStructure.module.js');
                    $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'app.organizationStructure'
                    });
                    deferred.resolve(mod.controller);
                });

                return deferred.promise;
       }]
    }
```

Here is the ui-router API doc for this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Answer (score 4):

> While doing minification you should for array annotation of DI.

You are not using angular di array notation inside you app.js, you need to do below changes.

**From**

```
app.config(routeConfig);
```

**To**

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', routeConfig]);
```

For more Information Refer [**this SO Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29705558/2435473)

Comment: Dependencies are automatically injected by ng-annotate-webpack-plugin. When webpack uglify the code, the resolve blocks the routing. Please help me find the error in this code:
resolve: ["$q", "$ocLazyLoad", function(e, t) {
                    var r = e.defer();
                    return n.e(1, function() {
                        var e = n(29);
                        t.load({
                            name: "app.organizationStructure"
                        }), r.resolve(e.controller)
                    }), r.promise
                }]

Comment: what if you wrote resolve function as `resolve: function($q, $ocLazyLoad) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();

                    require.ensure([], function() {
                        var mod = require('./organizationStructure.module.js');
                        $ocLazyLoad.load({
                            name: 'app.organizationStructure'
                        });
                        deferred.resolve(mod.controller);
                    });

                    return deferred.promise;
                }` does it is giving an error?

Comment: @AjayKumar which angular version you are using? without using `$ocLazyLoad` dependancy, does it work?

Comment: I am using Angular 1.2.28. I havent tried it without $ocLazyLoad. But it works in unminified code. Theoretically it should also work in minified code.

Comment: yes, Theoretically it should work, but checking that possibility by asking you,,

Comment: I removed ocLazyLoad, I registered the module and it is loaded on app start. App works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75747/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-ajay-kumar).