# oclazyLoad with webpack to support lazy loading for Angularjs is not working on minification

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I am using oclazyLoad with webpack to support lazy loading for Angularjs based single page application. It works very good when files are not in compressed. However when I run webpack Profileion build then all files are minified which is great but my application stops working. Router is not able to load. Following is code sample.

**Main App.js as entry file:**

```
/* App.js */
// you need these two lines so that webpack can fetch the chunked bundles from the proper path
// or else it'll try to get them as a root relative path
if (location.protocol === 'https:') {
    __webpack_public_path__ = 'https://' + window.location.host + '/js/';
} else {
    __webpack_public_path__ = 'http://' + window.location.host + '/js/';
} 
var angular = require("angular");
require("angular-ui-router");
require("angular-resource");
require("angular-sanitize");
require("oclazyLoad");

require("./../../../utilities/JavascriptExtension");

var Routers = require("./routers/Routers");

require('./Main');
//Get Angular Project module
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ['ngResource', 'ui.router', 'ngSanitize', 'MyApp.main', 'oc.lazyLoad']);


//Add client side routers
app.config(Routers.routes);
//Enable html5 mode
app.config(Routers.html5mode);

//Add onscroll event
//app.run(Routers.onscroll);
```

**Router File:**

```
'use strict';
/* Routers.js */
module.exports = {
    routes: ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            //Set the default route
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/myapp/see-all-business-credit-cards');
            //Define routes for view   (Please make sure the most matched pattern is define at top)
            $stateProvider
                    .state('viewallcards', {
                        url: '/myapp/see-all-business-credit-cards/:eep',
                        params: {
                            eep: {squash: true, value: null}
                        },
                        templateProvider: ['$q', function ($q) {
                                var deferred = $q.defer();
                                // note that the file name needs to be repeated in the require.ensure([...]) block 
                                // if you're going to use the uglifyJS plugin. It breaks otherwise.
                                require.ensure(['html!./../../../templates/partials/AllProfile.html'], function (require) {
                                    var template = require('html!./../../../templates/partials/AllProfile.html');
                                    deferred.resolve(template);
                                });
                                return deferred.promise;
                            }],
                        controller: 'AllProfileController',
                        resolve: ['$q', '$ocLazyLoad', function ($q, $ocLazyLoad) {
                                var deferred = $q.defer();

                                require.ensure([], function () {
                                    var mod = require('./../AllProfiles');
                                    $ocLazyLoad.load({
                                        name: 'MyApp.allProfiles'
                                    });
                                    deferred.resolve(mod.controller);
                                });

                                return deferred.promise;
                            }]
                    })
                    .state('Profilepage', {
                        url: '/myapp/:ProfileKey/:eep',
                        params: {
                            eep: {squash: true, value: null}
                        },
                        templateProvider: ['$q', function ($q) {
                                var deferred = $q.defer();
                                // note that the file name needs to be repeated in the require.ensure([...]) block 
                                // if you're going to use the uglifyJS plugin. It breaks otherwise.
                                require.ensure(['html!./../../../templates/partials/ProfilePageView.html'], function (require) {
                                    var template = require('html!./../../../templates//Profilepage/ProfilePageView.html');
                                    deferred.resolve(template);
                                });
                                return deferred.promise;
                            }],
                        controller: 'ProfilePageViewController',
                        resolve: ['$q', '$ocLazyLoad', function ($q, $ocLazyLoad) {
                                var deferred = $q.defer();

                                require.ensure([], function () {
                                    var mod = require('./../ProfilePage');
                                    $ocLazyLoad.load({
                                        name: 'MyApp.Profilepage'
                                    });
                                    deferred.resolve(mod.controller);
                                });

                                return deferred.promise;
                            }]
                    });
        }],
    html5mode: ["$locationProvider", function ($locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        }]
};
```

Following is webpack.config.js

```
var webpackConfig = {
    context: __dirname + '/application/client-src/js/application',
    entry: './App.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/application/public/js',
        filename: 'open-site.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('common.js'),
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css"},
            {test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=1000000&mimetype=image/png"},
            {test: /\.jpg$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=1000000&mimetype=image/jpg"}
        ]
    }

};
```

Please help

Comment: I answered this in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729242/webpack-uglify-causes-routing-to-stop-work/29798530#29798530

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't search this post before. It worked :-)

Comment: & I read your post on webpack too. It is written very nicely. You can mention this point there too to help others :-)